# How to consume reusable gui element/widget with resources in android

Tags: android, resources, android-widget

I try to use the [dateslider](http://code.google.com/p/android-dateslider/) in my android project to have a combined date-time picker im my gui.

The authors of the widget suggest to include the java- and resource-sources directly into my app.

**1st try** copy java and resources into main app:

**Result:** The widget java classes **cannot compile** because the resourceids R.xxxx cannot be resolved.

**Reason:** The widget classes are implemented in package "com.googlecode.android.widgets.DateSlider" and my app 
has a different namespace "my.namespace.myApp" so that the resourceids come from my.namespace.myApp.R.xxx.

**To fix** this i would have to touch every widget java source to import my.namespace.myApp.

Is there a way to have 2 resource-sets with different namespaces so that there are my.namespace.myApp.R.xxx and com.googlecode.android.widgets.DateSlider.R in the main app?

**2nd try** put widget java+resources into seperate jar/library:

**result:** every thing compiled. but after appstart i get a **runtimererror:** the runtime cannot resolve the widget resource IDs from the jar/lib.

Note: i can call methods from the jar as long as these do not need resources.

So my question: what is the best way to consume a reusable gui element with resources in android?

I am using android 2.2.

Note: [Android: How do I create reusable components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300276/android-how-do-i-create-reusable-components) does not help because it tells you how to create library-projects.

**update 16.3.2012**

Since the current version 16 /17-pre of of the eclipse adt-tools do not support resources in jars (as of try 2) what is the best/easiest way to consume them until there is support for this?

**update 4.4.2012**

with the new R17-tools i succeeded to consume libraryproject-with-resources that creates the jar. Android-Lint helped me to find out what to change in the lib to make it usable.

- eclipse-workspace

  - DateSliberLib

    - src
    - res
    - ...
  - MyAppUsingLib

    - src
    - res
    - ...

  with this layout MyAppUsingLib is running fine

---

However I am still not able to use the DateSliberlib.jar alone

- eclipse-workspace

  - MyAppUsingLib

    - src
    - res
    - lib

      - DateSliberLib.jar
    - ...

This setting can be comiled but the app crashes because it cannot find the resources of the lib.

[update 2014-11-17]

6 months ago i switched from eclipse/ant-build to android-studio/gradle build which introduced *.aar files that are jar-files with android resources.

android-studio/gradle build can cope with resources in libs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to have 2 resource-sets with different namespaces so that there are my.namespace.myApp.R.xxx and com.googlecode.android.widgets.DateSlider.R in the main app?

No, sorry.

> Note: Android: How do I create reusable components? does not help because it tells you how to create library-projects.

However, that *is* the right answer. Download the full project from their repo, import it into Eclipse, and mark it as a library project (Properties > Android). Then, add it as a library project to your app's project.

Eventually (which now appears like it will be the R18 version of tools or later), the tools should support packaging reusable components in a JAR, with resources, in such a manner that you can add them to a host project and the resources will be blended in automatically. Right now, that's not an option.

Comment: If i understood you correctly my 2nd try was correct to make a jar out of it and i need to update the eclipse adt-tools from 15 to 18 and it should work then. I will give it a try. Thanks

Comment: @k3b: R18 tools do not exist yet. As I wrote, "***eventually*** (which now appears like it will be the R18 version of tools or later), the tools should support packaging reusable components in a JAR".

Comment: +1 for info about adttools. I reformulated the question to best practise until adt supports it. thank you very much for info

Comment: @k3b: I already answered your modified question. Download the full project from their repo, import it into Eclipse, and mark it as a library project (Properties > Android). Then, add it as a library project to your app's project.

Comment: Today i upgraded to R17 tools. With this i can consume the lib after minimal changes in the layout-file that the android lint tool discovered