# View or Fragment library to compose UI for common data types

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-intent, android-widget

### Problem

- [Reusables@common.com](http://mailto%3aReusables@common.com)
- £1,000,000
- [www.inventing-a-wheel.ee](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921153%28PandP.40%29.aspx#sec2)
- Action Shortcut: <kbd>C</kbd>

I need to let the user enter an email, pick a date, edit a webpage, choose an image etc - there are a number of common presentation tasks that are not **directly** subserved by the Android SDK widget library and so I thought there may be a dedicated repository or framework available that specializes in such UI concerns.

[ *While Android provides widgets that can be turned into specific editors for email, for instance, the question here regards finding a library of ready-made components that specifically target such common data types i.e. UI elements which are specifically geared towards presenting such data, out-of-the-box, as well as providing validation.* ]

### Existing Sources?

So I searched the web with a combination of terms like `Android`, `widget`, `library`, `view`, `toolkit`, `fragment`, `repository`, but came up with false positives only.

Could you refer me to any collective efforts that provide a list of classes / XML layouts [implementing common data-specific input / editing / configuration elements](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=IntegerUpDown&referringTitle=Home)?

So I could do something like this in ActivityA1, ActivityA3, ActivityB1, ActivityN9:

- new EmailEditText()
- new UrlTextView()
- new IPView() ...

### Matching Data to Views?

What I'm really looking for is a set of widgets that would be resolved according to the data that needs to be presented, perhaps similarly to [implicit intent resolution](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html#ires) ?

So from my domain model I would provide some data with a specific data type, which should be displayed somehow appropriately. But I do not explicitly set what View will present this data, instead there is a matcher inbetween that filters a list of available specific-purpose views and selects the most appropriate one for the given data type.

Anything like that out there already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, Android doesn't have exactly what you want, but don't worry - there are definitely things to make your life easier.

For example, you can set the [`inputType`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType) on an EditText to change what the keyboard looks like (eg. for e-mail you have "@" and ".com" buttons, for a phone number you have numbers) and  use [InputFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.html) to control data entry.

You can even use `EditText.setTransformationMethod()` to change the way the data is presented (like adding spaces in a phone number).

And if you want to pick an image, you can send off an intent to request it: http://android-er.blogspot.se/2011/02/select-image-using-android-build-in.html

It shouldn't be too hard building your own set of widgets that does just what you want by combining these approaches.

**Update:** There is now a library available that makes form validation easier: https://github.com/vekexasia/android-form-edittext

Comment: while Android provides many almost fully-baked UI elements I feel we are still wasting collective effort on re-inventing the wheel - I'm aware of the customizations you mention but why not offer them as a ready-made package for common UI tasks, and add appropriate validation as well (new EmailEditText()), instead of everyone (re-)implementing their own. and then there are additional widgets e.g. enter an IP that are needed pretty frequently, but that Android does not provide... from lack of any links to libraries i have a feeling im gonna have to tread that same path though :( hope dies last.

Comment: I find that usually, it's simple enough to use these customizations to achieve what you want. Android is designed to be easy to extend, so most of the times you don't even need to subclass the widgets to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [dateslider](http://code.google.com/p/android-dateslider/) componenet to implement mixed date-time inputelements.

However accourding to [my experiences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721860/how-to-consume-reusable-gui-element-widget-with-resources-in-android) the current android development tools adt (at least version 17 but probably until version 19) are currently not able to handle jar-files with resources properly. you have to include the library sources to build a project with widgets.

Comment: ive been using layouts, drawables and values from many chained libraries included with source code, but had no idea this could not be closed up! this leaves room for any open source efforts though.. and thanks for the dateslider link.